# when sending service bus messages using REST API?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm sending service messages to my client via REST API. I included the message ID in the request header and received 201, indicating that the message was successfully created.

However, the message I sent was not received by the client. And they're asking for proof that the message was delivered successfully. Essentially, they are asking for the message ID that we receive from Microsoft once the message is created.

In the response, I did not receive an ID. Will Microsoft include the message ID I sent in the header? Or will they have a unique ID?

I want to know if MS use the same message ID

Comment: Please share the rest API call(header, url, body, parameters) and the response.

Comment: Do you want to send message to service bus queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when sending service bus messages using REST API?did not receive an ID. Will Microsoft include the message ID I sent in the header? Or will they have a unique ID?
> I want to know if MS use the same message ID

To send message id and set message id, you can use below c# code which uses rest api and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#c) and modified code from the document:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

public class Program
{
    const string ServiceBusNamespace = "testservicebus098";
    const string QueueName = "rithwik";
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var servicebusurl = "testservicebus098.servicebus.windows.net";
        var keyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
        var primarykey = "r5l9xk4fCkQ0+SbM5mufk=";
        TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
        var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + week);
        string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(servicebusurl) + "\n" + expiry;
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(primarykey));
        var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
        var rith_sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(servicebusurl), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);
        

        string rithwik_message = "Hello Rithwik Bojja, Message sent from Rest API!";
        var rith_message = new { message = rithwik_message };
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rith_message);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.Add("Sender", "Rithwik Bojja");
        var brokerProperties = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            MessageId = "0008"
        });
        content.Headers.Add("BrokerProperties", brokerProperties);

        var rith_httpClient = new HttpClient();
        rith_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", rith_sasToken);
        var rith_result = await rith_httpClient.PostAsync($"https://{ServiceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{QueueName}/messages", content);

        if (rith_result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully.");
        }
    }

}
```

To send message you need to have SAS token, i have generated sas token by following [microsoft-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#c) and then sent it using rest api.

To get primarykey and keyname :

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Using above code you can set Message Id and even other properties.